# Recursively create a folder in typescript in VS Code Extension

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, fs, vscode-extensions

Im trying to create a folder in a workspace on disc but I am unable to create it.

```
var fs2 = require("fs");
fs2.mkdirSync(absolutePath, {recursive: true});
```

Above is my code. Im using Node.js version 11.6.0 which should have a recursive option available but calling the above code fails and throws 'Error ENOENT: no such file or directory.' Path is an absolute path from root of the C: drive.

> c:\Users\myusername\Desktop\VS Code Workspaces\Workspaces\TestWorkspace\src\state\ducks\quack'

Up until TestWorkspace exists - `src\state\ducks\quack` does not.

What am I doing wrong?
I tried to make a comment on an existing question by I dont have enough reputation to add comments so had to ask a new question...

Comment: For a test try to create all subpaths manually, dir by dir, to see if that produces any problem (maybe there's an access problem).

Comment: There is no access problem. I know I can create these folders. What is the problem is that even though Node 11 is installed on my machine my extension is only using  the version currently installed with VS Code. Which coincidentally happens to be a version that does not support the recursive option.